# How to SET PostgreSQL runtime configuration variables safely using typeorm API

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, connection-pooling, typeorm

There is a nodeJS web server (using nestJS) connecting to typeorm with a single connection (by typeorm's docs, its a connection pool).

The server have http endpoints - the server API.

When the server receive a request it authenticate the user, if the user can access, it invoke a method that execute queries to the database.

#### Question

How can I set runtime variables safely to the DB so that I can be sure that the variables sync with each app user (due to the http request triggered the execution)?

I saw that it is possible to set local variables in a transaction but I wouldn't like to wrap all the queries with transactions.

For example:

```
--- project.service.ts
   import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';

   async findOneById(id: number): Promise<Project> {
----> Something like: getConnection().query(`SET app.config = $1;`, [thisUserConfig])
        return await Project.findOne({ id });
    }
```